# Ajax and returning image created by PHP GD

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, php-gd

I have a PHP script that generates an image with PHP GD. After it generates the image, it saves it, and send this output when called by Ajax:

```
imagejpeg($img_data, 'filename.jpg');
echo '<img src="/filename.jpg.jpg">';
```

And after that, the image is shown on the page, and everything is fine. But, I don't want to create an image every time. Is there some way that I return by Ajax only `$raw_data` string and show the image? I tried like this:

```
echo $img_data;
```

But no luck, only thing that is returned is a few ?.

Here is my jQuery Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    action: 'update_image',
    //some instructions for creating the image
  },
  url: 'script.php',
  success: function(msg) {
    $('#somediv').append(msg);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

base64 encode the image and return that, then you can do an `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA......." />`

On the PHP side

```
$image = base64_encode($imageGDRender);
echo json_encode(array('image'=>$image));
```

That will return your json back to your jquery

then on the ajax side

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        var base64Image = data.image;
        ...now put it in your image
        $('#image').attr('src','data:image...'+base64Image);
    })....
```

Comment: I am unsure how to implement this? As I can google about this, i need some "json encoding" to achieve this or something like that?

Comment: Tnx, but still instead of image data, i get "undefined". But this helped me to search in right place. I put solution in answer below.

Comment: Note that you'll lose caching

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution:

PHP code:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($im);
$outputBuffer = ob_get_clean();
$base64 = base64_encode($outputBuffer);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$base64.'" />';
```

On user side (in JQuery):

```
success: function(data) {
        $('#somediv').append(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the header before doing the `echo $img_data;`

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: " .sizeof($img_data));
```

Comment: Result is same when i do this, nothing changes.