# jQuery ajax response to return formatted HTML

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending some variables from mypage.php to ajax.php page. On ajax.php I check some conditions and compiled some HTML based on request. Now I need to return that formatted HTML back to mypage.php and display. I do see request sent and response in my dev tools, however nothing seems to render on return. What am I missing?

**mypage.php**

```
<div id="myContainer"></div>


// JS
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "ajax.php",
    data: {
        "op": "html",
        "wd": wd
    },
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(response)
        $("#myContainer").append(response.images);
    }
});
```

**ajax.php**

```
// php code here creating $images

echo '{ "images": "'.$images.'" }';
```

Comment: What do you see if you console.log `response` in the success callback?

Comment: I've added test console.log("test"); and I see it come up in console, so i know it's success. I don't get any errors or warnings.

Comment: Don't console.log `test` which has no meaning, log the `response` variable that should contain the response from your script. E.g. `console.log(response, typeof response)`

Comment: I think I have something in HTML that breaks it. When I use base64_encode on php side I see the string output. I guess I need to encode with PHP and decode with JS to see the output. Is there such a thing?

Comment: seems atob() works.

Comment: Don't construct JSON by hand. Use `echo json_encode(["images" => $images]);`

Comment: base64_encode ur image & return back  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144479/ajax-and-returning-image-created-by-php-gd